# IntelliJ Find Action on Mac opens terminal app by error

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

When I press <kbd>Cmd + Shift + A</kbd> in IntelliJ it should open the "Find Action..." dialog. Instead it opens Terminal.app with the `apropos` command.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Seems in MacOs 10.14.4 a new default shortcut was enabled - Services -> Search man Page Index in Terminal. It uses the same shortcut as `Find Action` - `Cmd+Shift+A`. As a result using Find Action in the IDE could sometimes open terminal window with `apropos <smth>` command output.[image]

Comment: Thanks for this fix. It was really annoying!

Comment: This seems like a bug in IntelliJ though  because `Cmd + Shift + A` does not cause this from any other application

Comment: flawless answer!

Comment: For Mac OS 13.X, the option is under 'TEXT' Heading under the same services tab

Answer (score 1):

**Explicit Location**: System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services (on left hand side) > (uncheck) Search man Page Index in Terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a script ([hosted in gist](https://gist.github.com/mrmanc/72eb1712472242e8962661f59ea60ca8)) that will do this via the command line, which might be useful for an organisation that wants to roll out this change for a number of users.

```sh
TEMP_SETTINGS_FILE=$(mktemp -t 'man-shortcuts-off.json')
cat > $TEMP_SETTINGS_FILE <<EOF
{
  "NSServicesStatus": {
    "com.apple.Terminal - Open man Page in Terminal - openManPage": {
      "presentation_modes": {
        "ContextMenu": false,
        "ServicesMenu": false
      },
      "enabled_context_menu": false,
      "enabled_services_menu": false
    },
    "com.apple.Terminal - Search man Page Index in Terminal - searchManPages": {
      "presentation_modes": {
        "ContextMenu": false,
        "ServicesMenu": false
      },
      "enabled_context_menu": false,
      "enabled_services_menu": false
    }
  }
}
EOF
# Settings are stored in the pbs domain. Other settings in this domain will not be overwritten. I’ve included the settings to change in JSON for brevity. They are converted to XML (which `defaults import` expects) before being imported.
plutil -convert xml1 -o - ${TEMP_SETTINGS_FILE} | defaults import pbs -
rm ${TEMP_SETTINGS_FILE}
```

Answer (score -1):

Intellij File search problem.
Issue observed when searching file inMAC

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C90Nb.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEzEn.png)

Comment: you could make the image to be viewed inplace by `[![enter image description here][1]][1]`.